# Calculate the splice event's time from pts time in SCTE 35 message

Tags: c++, mpeg2-ts

As I saw in the document, `pts_time` field often carries relative PTS from the network program start. But I don't know how to calculate the time of the splice event in the normal clock time `(dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ms)` based on this `pts_time` value.

For example:
An SCTE 35 cue out message with the `pts_time` value is 58855 Mhz. How can I calculate the actual time that the splice event occurs?

Answer (score 1):

From the SCTE-35 spec: (http://www.scte.org/documents/pdf/standards/Top%20Ten/ANSI_SCTE%2035%202013.pdf):

> pts_time – A 33-bit field that indicates time in terms of ticks of the program’s 90 kHz clock. This field, when modified by pts_adjustment, represents the time of the intended splice point

Therefore it's: 58855 / 90000 = 0.6539444444444444 seconds

You'll need to apply pts_adjustment and it's relative to PTS

Answer (score 0):

How are you receiving the incoming message? Usually the `SCTE35` Splice info section is contained within something like a `SCTE30` `Cue Request` message.

If you explore section 7.4.1 of the [SCTE30 standard](https://www.scte.org/documents/pdf/Standards/ANSI_SCTE%2030%202009.pdf) you'll find:

> time( )  –
>   - This time is derived from the splice_time(  ) in the splice_info_section( ) of the  SCTE 35 Cueing Message by the Splicer.
>   If component splice mode is used in the SCTE 35 splice_info_section,
>   the time( ) will refer to  the default splice time detailed in Section
>   7.5.2.1  of SCTE 35.

Essentially, the UTC time contained within the Cue Request is the time you're after (at least, that's how we've implemented it).

Answer (score 0):

pts_time does not translate directly into a specific clock time.
PTS rolls over at 8589934591, every 95443.717678 seconds on a 90k clock.